# Windows 7: Remote desktop connection - does it show what I am doing remotely in the host machine?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

In remote desktop connection to Windows 7 Professional, does the host machine display what I am doing remotely in the host machine or is it a totally different session?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the manner by which you connect and the server's operating system.

However, normally it is a separate session for you only, especially if the host is a server. If the host is not a server, normally by connecting you will log-out automatically the console session.

But you should be aware that if the host machine is a server version, the administrator can connect to your session and see everything you do. He also has quite a few other tools to find out what you are doing even if he doesn't watch your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

On the desktop versions, yes. Where you're in control of a different session, it would be closer to terminal server. However some early XP builds let you run a seperate session, having rudimentary terminal server capabilities, but this was eventually taken out.